# Force java application use different them than default GTK

Tags: java, arduino, gtk, themes

I want to force arduino(Java based application) use Adwaita:light theme instead of default dark theme, I tried following approach for binary application gedit and work well:

```
env GTK_THEME="Adwaita:light" gedit
```

but seems no effect on java and still follow default dark theme.

*ps: I'm using fedora 26 workstation, GTK 3.22*

Comment: Java seems to be using gtk2. Try GTK2_RC_FILES.

Comment: I also try that but not work.